# How to hide updates in Windows Updates?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I have Windows 7 Ultimate, and it has 34 Languages as Optional Windows Updates.

I probably will install 1 or 2, but I don't think I will learn the other 32 languages in the next few years, so is there a way to just turn them off instead of having them show up all the time and mix in with other more important optional updates?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Steps to hide Windows Updates:

> - Open Windows Updates
> - Click on View Updates
> - Right click on the item you want to hide
> - Click on Hide

You can also select multiple updates by holding <kbd>shift</kbd> or <kbd>control</kbd>.

Comment: I couldn't find Windows UpdateS  only Windows Update.  And in that Window, there is no View Updates, only View Update History. And when I click on that it and then right-click a Failed update, it doesn't give me a choice to Hide. It gives me only View Details  and Copy Details. The former gives me no options for Hide.

Comment: @Clay. You can only see the updates once you have done a check and there is some available to download.