# Disable updates

Tags: windows-8, windows-update

The three updates below are always provided as part of Windows Security Updates. I hardly consider them security related or essential. But they are a distraction because I have to check what's available whenever Windows Update notifies something is available.

[image]

How do I remove them from the list of available updates?

Comment: "I hardly consider them security related or essential" - That's why they're categorized as "Optional". :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide updates in Windows Updates?](http://superuser.com/questions/72503/how-to-hide-updates-in-windows-updates)

Comment: Thanks techie007. I'd prefer to permanently remove them like an ActiveX Killbits file rather than just hide them.

Comment: You may want to edit your question and add that bit of info. As it stands, it just says to want to disable them from view, which is what hiding them does.

Comment: Well, I did say I want to remove them, not hide them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable irrelevant Windows Updates](http://superuser.com/questions/55410/how-to-disable-irrelevant-windows-updates?rq=1)

Comment: "Remove them from the list" is a bit vague, and to me means you just don't want them in the list, not that you want to prevent Windows update from tracking/providing that update completely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you click on the updates, you can right click on them and then select Hide Update. This will prevent it from being displayed in the list.

[image]

Comment: You might have to repeat this procedure multiple times, as each version is a separate update. Hiding Bing 1.3.1 makes Bing 1.3 pop up on the next check and so on.

Comment: Thanks kobaltz. How does one do that? They are not hot linked, so when I click on them nothing happens. I can select them with the check box, but the only choice is Install.

Comment: When you click on it, it should highlight the row in which case you can then right click on the item.

Comment: @DanielB that is correct. Also nice to note that if they are in a group like in the image I posted above, you can click on the group name to select the whole list and then right click on one of them to hide update for all selected.